# How to add a plugin jar into the DITA OT classpath?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I am writing a plugin for DITA-OT PDF2. In this plugin I need to define extension functions for Saxon XSLT. I followed the tutorials from the dita-ot website:
https://www.dita-ot.org/3.3/topics/implement-saxon-extension-functions.html
and 
https://www.dita-ot.org/3.3/topics/plugin-javalib.html

Note: I am using DITA OT 3.3.1

I have this feature in my plugin, pointing to the jar that contains my extension functions:

`<feature extension="dita.conductor.lib.import" file="./xslt-extension.jar"/>`

I get this error:

```
transform.topic2fo.main:
 [pipeline] Static error in {ftd:lastApplicability()} in expression in xsl:variable/@select on line 30 column 79 of applicability.xsl:
 [pipeline]   XPST0017: Cannot find a 0-argument function named {https://orlandotechpubs.com/}lastApplicability()
 [pipeline] Static error near {...eApplicability($applicabili...} in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 99 column 69 of applicability.xsl:
 [pipeline]   XPST0017: Cannot find a 1-argument function named {https://orlandotechpubs.com/}writeApplicability()

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\d_bo\Desktop\test-dita-ot-pdf\test\sample_pdf.xml:9: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\d_bo\Desktop\test-dita-ot-pdf\dita-ot-3.3.1\plugins\org.dita.base\build.xml:31: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\d_bo\Desktop\test-dita-ot-pdf\dita-ot-3.3.1\plugins\org.dita.pdf2\build.xml:151: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\d_bo\Desktop\test-dita-ot-pdf\dita-ot-3.3.1\plugins\org.dita.pdf2\build.xml:291: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to compile stylesheet 'C:\Users\d_bo\Desktop\test-dita-ot-pdf\dita-ot-3.3.1\plugins\org.dita.pdf2.axf\xsl\fo\topic2fo_shell_axf.xsl': net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
    at org.dita.dost.module.XsltModule.execute(XsltModule.java:108)
    at org.dita.dost.ant.ExtensibleAntInvoker.execute(ExtensibleAntInvoker.java:182)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:158)
    at org.dita.dost.module.XsltModule.execute(XsltModule.java:106)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:742)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:155)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(StylesheetModule.java:260)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:106)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:739)
    ... 58 more
```

I double checked everything and my extension functions are correctly defined. So I did some tests and apparently my jar is never added to the classpath. I created a simple ant target and launched again:

```
    <target name="testJava">
      <java classname="com.infotel.ftd.MyTest">
      </java>
    </target>
```

Here is what I get:

```
     [java] Could not find com.infotel.ftd.MyTest. Make sure you have it in your classpath
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:141)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:861)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:231)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
     [java] Java Result: -1
```

**How can I debug dita OT to see what is wrong with my configuration?**

Comment: What you do in the plugin.xml looks fine.Have you followed step 3 in the first link you posted, namely to have inside the JAR library a " META-INF" folder with a "services" file containing the fully qualified name of the class which extends the Saxon function API?

Comment: An example of a DITA OT plugin which actually works (you can look in the "latexToSVG.jar" library and at how the "com.oxygenxml.latex.svg.LatexToSVG" class implements the Saxon "ExtensionFunctionDefinition" interface): https://github.com/oxygenxml/dita-latex

Answer (score 2):

I finally nailed what was wrong with my DITA OT configuration.

I was using an [ant build script](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.3/topics/publishing-with-ant.html) to run DITA OT and when doing this, the plugin JARs are not automatically added to the classpath.

**I switched to [using the DITA OT command line](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.3/topics/build-using-dita-command.html).** Now my JARs are seen by the ant scripts and my extension functions are accessible from the XSLT.

In addition, if someone else has a classpath problem like this, you can also check the file [DITA-OT]/config/env.bat (env.sh for lunix users). After installing a plugin that provides its own JAR libraries, the JAR files shall be present in this file:

```
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DITA_HOME%\plugins\org.dita.pdf2\lib\fo.jar"
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DITA_HOME%\plugins\com.infotel.orlando.pdf\.\xslt-extension.jar"
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DITA_HOME%\plugins\org.dita.eclipsehelp\lib\eclipsehelp.jar"
...
```